# Difference between ( for... in ) and ( for... of ) statements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object

I know what is a `for... in` loop (it iterates over the keys), but I have heard about `for... of` for the first time (it iterates over values).

I am confused about `for... of` loop.

```js
var arr = [3, 5, 7];
arr.foo = "hello";
    
for (var i in arr) {
  console.log(i); // logs "0", "1", "2", "foo"
}
    
for (var i of arr) {
  console.log(i); // logs "3", "5", "7"
  // it doesn't log "3", "5", "7", "hello"
}
```

I understand that `for... of` iterates over property values. Then why doesn't it log `"3", "5", "7", "hello"` instead of `"3", "5", "7"`?

Unlike `for... in` loop, which iterates over each key (`"0", "1", "2", "foo"`) and also iterates over the `foo` key, the `for... of` *does not* iterate over the value of `foo` property, i.e., `"hello"`. Why it is like that?

Here I console `for... of` loop. It should log `"3", "5", "7","hello"` but it logs `"3", "5", "7"`. Why?

[Example Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement)

Comment: in the case you miss it, here is the inception link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: As far as my understanding goes, `for ... of` was brought into the language to fix the problems with using `for ... in` with Arrays. `Array.prototype` could be amended in such a way that extra properties are available, making it unsafe to iterate them as you could get non numeric keys that you weren't expecting.

Comment: For future readers: this is probably not a duplicate of [JavaScript `of` Keyword (for…of loops)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525695/javascript-of-keyword-for-of-loops), since it asks about a specific behavior of the feature, rather than asking for a general overview.

Comment: Just get to used to saying "`for <key> in`" and "`for <value> of`" and realize IE doesn't support `for..of`

Comment: @BotNet "realize IE doesn't support `for..of`" While that's technically true, most modern projects use Babel anyway.

Answer (score 801, accepted):

[`for in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loops over enumerable property names of an object.

[`for of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) (new in ES6) does use an [object-specific *iterator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) and loops over the values generated by that.

In your example, the [array iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator) does yield all the values in the array (ignoring non-index properties).

Comment: IE doesn't yet support For of, Chrome, Firefox, and Edge do

Comment: A mnemonic: 'o'f -> not 'o'bjects, 'i'n -> not 'i'terables

Comment: another mnemonic: `for... of` :: arrays :: arrays always have a length, so you can think `for.. ` *[nth element]* `of.. ` *[q elements]*

Comment: Another mnemonic...`for..in..keys` === foreign keys === use `for...in` for keys! As such, use `for...of` for values.

Comment: these names are confusion prone... bad choice of names

Comment: @Placoplatr For that mnemonic, you have to remember that it's "NOT" rather than "IS". And midst all the other mnemonics that flip the negative, you forget which ones are flipped and which ones are not.

So any mnemonic that relies on a negation is doesn't work at scale imo. If you're focused only on javascript, good enough.

Comment: `in` gives you index. This is more than enough to remember the difference. If you apply logic on other fronts.

Comment: Not particularly relevant anymore but was it acceptable to use for...in with non-enumerables before ES6? Found some old code that uses it like that, just curious really

Comment: @AllieHowe What do you mean by "*non-enumerables*"? If the object has properties that are not enumerable, `for … in` won't enumerate them.

Comment: From some article I read: Think about pearls of a necklace and words in a dictionary. Pearls **of** a necklace is an array of pearls. Words **in** a dictionary is an object. Use **of** to loop through arrays. Use **in** to loop through objects.

Comment: `for...in` ⇒ keys ***in*** an object — `for...of` ⇒ items ***of*** an array

Comment: Honestly the best mnemonic for me is "for...in was first and got the good name for the easier thing, enumerable properties. for...of does iterators which came later and is more difficult, so its name sucks"

Comment: NodeList looks like any array but it requires for of. Why is that?

Comment: @Alston Any array should be used with `for … of`, not with `for … in`? But yes, [a nodelist is not an array](https://www.clairecodes.com/blog/2015-12-01-nodelists-are-not-arrays/) (mostly for history reasons), at least it has been made iterable for convenience.

Comment: The mnemonic I use is "`for...in` is 'foreign'--because you shouldn't use it." XD `Object.keys(obj)` is almost always a better choice.

Comment: Note that `for...in` could be used for iterables such as array-like objects, but is considered bad practice cause it doesn't guarantee order, iterates over inherited enumerable properties, and is usually slower https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-for-array-iteration-a-bad-idea

Comment: @AidenCullo No it could not! It does not iterate them, it enumerates their properties, if they have any. It does not work on `Map` instances for example.

Comment: One more mnemonic! `for...of` replaces `for (let i = 0; ...)`, so `for...0f`. I haven't been able to remember the difference reliably without this one.

Comment: I keep `for...in` and `for...of` straight in my mind by simply remembering that the words **in** and **enumerable** both begin with the same syllable, therefore they go together.

Answer (score 648):

I found a complete answer at [Iterators and Generators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html) (Although it is for TypeScript, this is the same for JavaScript too)

> Both `for..of` and `for..in` statements iterate over lists; the values
> iterated on are different though, `for..in` returns a list of keys on
> the object being iterated, whereas `for..of` returns a list of values
> of the numeric properties of the object being iterated.
>
> Here is an example that demonstrates this distinction:
>
> ```
> let list = [4, 5, 6];
>
> for (let i in list) {
>    console.log(i); // "0", "1", "2",
> }
>
> for (let i of list) {
>    console.log(i); // "4", "5", "6"
> }
> ```
>
> Another distinction is that `for..in` operates on any object; it serves
> as a way to inspect properties on this object. `for..of` on the other
> hand, is mainly interested in values of iterable objects. Built-in
> objects like `Map` and `Set` implement `Symbol.iterator` property allowing
> access to stored values.
>
> ```
> let pets = new Set(["Cat", "Dog", "Hamster"]);
> pets["species"] = "mammals";
>
> for (let pet in pets) {
>    console.log(pet); // "species"
> }
>
> for (let pet of pets) {
>     console.log(pet); // "Cat", "Dog", "Hamster"
> }
> ```

Comment: Futhermore, calling something like for(let i of {}) { console.log(i); } would throw an TypeError: VM391:1 Uncaught TypeError: {} is not iterable
    at <anonymous>:1:14, at least in Chrome

Comment: TS for the win - the example is incorrect, the latter should return "mammals", not // "Cat", "Dog", "Hamster"

Comment: I remember it by: for "in" for `index`.  And then for "of" would be the `values` of each index/key/item.

Comment: Nice, this is going to be king for me: using for-ins for iteration of items I usually have to create a `let thisItem = items[all];` variable, `for...of` helps shortcut that!

Comment: I remember it by: `for...in` as `Object.keys()`, guess what? Arrays are objects, sot that would also returns their indeces. :)

Comment: @SherylHohman Thank you, I finally have a way to remember it. `for...in-dex`

Comment: A note worth mentioning here: Indexes returned by ```for...in ``` are strings! ...in case you need to use the index here as a number you need to convert it e.g ```Number(i)```

Comment: @salouri That's why you shouldn't use `in` for arrays. Use a traditional for loop to run over an array and you will deal with numbers, the string to number conversion is unnecessary and the `in` approach should be slower because of that. `in` is more suited to iterating keys of an object, which one can call "indexes" to make this mnemonic work.

Answer (score 235):

### Difference `for..in` and `for..of`:

Both `for..in` and `for..of` are looping constructs which are used to iterate over data structures. The only difference between them is the entities
they iterate over:

1. `for..in` iterates over all enumerable **property keys of an object**
2. `for..of` iterates over the **values of an iterable object**. Examples of iterable objects are arrays, strings, and NodeLists.

### Example:

```js
let arr = ['el1', 'el2', 'el3'];

arr.addedProp = 'arrProp';

// elKey are the property keys
for (let elKey in arr) {
  console.log(elKey);
}

// elValue are the property values
for (let elValue of arr) {
  console.log(elValue)
}
```

In this example we can observe that the `for..in` loop iterates over the keys of the object, which is an array object in this example. The keys are 0, 1, 2 (which correspond to the array elements) and `addedProp`. This is how the `arr` array object looks in chrome devtools:

[image]

You see that our `for..in` loop does nothing more than simply iterating over these keys.

---

The `for..of` loop in our example iterates over the **values** of a data structure. The values in this specific example are `'el1', 'el2', 'el3'`. The values which an iterable data structure will return using `for..of` is dependent on the type of iterable object. For example an array will return the values of all the array elements whereas a string returns every individual character of the string.

Comment: why for of not outputting "arrProp" ?

Comment: @AlifRamdani In this case, specifically because the object in question is an Array. That's what @Willem meant with "The values which an iterable data structure will return using `for..of` is dependent on the type of iterable object." In the case of an Array, that's just numerical indexes.

Answer (score 55):

## For...in loop

The [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop improves upon the weaknesses of the for loop by eliminating the counting logic and exit condition.

Example:

```
const digits = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

for (const index in digits) {
  console.log(digits[index]);
}
```

But, you still have to deal with the issue of using an index to access the values of the array, and that stinks; it almost makes it more confusing than before.

Also, the for...in loop can get you into big trouble when you need to add an extra method to an array (or another object). Because for...in loops loop over all enumerable properties, this means if you add any additional properties to the array's prototype, then those properties will also appear in the loop.

```
Array.prototype.decimalfy = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    this[i] = this[i].toFixed(2);
  }
};

const digits = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

for (const index in digits) {
  console.log(digits[index]);
}
```

Prints:

> 0
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 6
>
> 7
>
> 8
>
> 9
>
> function() {
>        for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
>         this[i] = this[i].toFixed(2);
>        }
>       }

This is why for...in loops are discouraged when looping over arrays.

> **NOTE**: The **forEach loop** is another type of for loop in JavaScript.
>   However, [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is actually an array method, so it can only be used
>   exclusively with arrays. There is also no way to stop or break a
>   forEach loop. If you need that type of behavior in your loop, you’ll
>   have to use a basic for loop.

## For...of loop

The [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop is used to loop over any type of data that is iterable.

Example:

```
const digits = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

for (const digit of digits) {
  console.log(digit);
}
```

Prints:

> 0
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 6
>
> 7
>
> 8
>
> 9

This makes the for...of loop the most concise version of all the for loops.

But wait, there’s more! The for...of loop also has some additional benefits that fix the weaknesses of the for and for...in loops.

You can stop or break a for...of loop at anytime.

```
const digits = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

for (const digit of digits) {
  if (digit % 2 === 0) {
    continue;
  }
  console.log(digit);
}
```

Prints:

> 1
>
> 3
>
> 5
>
> 7
>
> 9

And you don’t have to worry about adding new properties to objects. The for...of loop will only loop over the values in the object.

Comment: "*The for...in loop improves upon the weaknesses of the for loop by eliminating the counting logic and exit condition*" - no, that's not what it does. Not at all.

Comment: @Bergi Could you maybe clarify why you think that's not what it does, and what you actually think it improves on?

Comment: It doesn't improve on anything, it has its own raison d'être. It does something totally different than a `for (var index=0; index<arr.length; index++)` loop (where the `index` counter is an integer, unlike in your example).

Comment: kind of makes it confusing that the array values you chose for the example correspond with the array index values...

Comment: Your example uses an array containing numbers from 0 to 9, which will confuse people as if they are indices, please change your source data to something more contextual.

Comment: @Bergi Mind explaining what you are talking about when claiming he ain't using `index` counter as an integer, because for as far as I can tell is that most if not all indexing variables used in provided answer are of integer type?

Comment: @Barrosy In `for (const index in digits)`, [the `index` is a **string**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2933737/1048572). It's neither a counter nor an integer, and that is very much a problem. Just [never use `for…in` enumerations on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)!

Comment: @Bergi Totally agree. Furthermore, I wouldn't recommend name that variable `index` at all and name it `key`, `propertyName` (or something like that) instead. E.g. `for (const key in digits)`. Because it is the meaning of it.

Answer (score 50):

Here is a useful mnemonic for remembering the difference between `for...in` Loop and `for...of` Loop.

**"index in, object of"**

`for...in Loop` => iterates over the **index in** the array.

`for...of Loop` => iterates over the **object of** objects.

Comment: what is "object of objects"?  it's better to say "the keys of the object"
but anyway, you will later remember "index of" instead of "index in" and "keys in" instead of "keys of" so that mnemonic is not perfect

Answer (score 31):

`for of` is used to iterate over iterables and `for in` is used to iterate over object properties

Here's a trick to remember:

`for of` is not for **o**bjects (so it's for iterables)

`for in` is not for **i**terables (so it's for objects)

Another trick:

`for in` returns object **in**dices (keys) while `for of` returns values

Comment: ah gotcha - so its the opposite of what i might expect it to be.  that should make it easy to remember.     thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 21):

//for in, iterates keys in an object and indexes in an array

```
 let obj={a:1, b:2}
    
    for( const key in obj)
      console.log(obj[key]); //would print 1 and 2
      console.log(key);      //would print a and b

 let arr = [10, 11, 12, 13];

  for (const item in arr) 
    console.log(item);   //would print 0 1 2 3
```

//for of, iterates values in an array or any iterable

```
let arr = [10, 11, 12, 13];

for (const item of arr )
  console.log(item);  //would print 10  11  12  13
```

Answer (score 16):

Short answer: `for...in` loops over **keys**, while `for...of` loops over **values**.

```
for (let x in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] {
    console.log(x); 
}

// Output
0
1
2
3


for (let x of ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] {
    console.log(x); 
}

// Output
a
b
c
d
```

Answer (score 15):

**Another difference** between the two loops, which nobody has mentioned before:

> Destructuring `for...in` is deprecated. Use `for...of` instead.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#Statements)

So if we want to use [*destructuring*](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html#_where-can-destructuring-be-used) in a loop, for get both *index* and *value* of each *array* element, we should to use the `for...of` loop with the *Array* method [`entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries):

```
for (const [idx, el] of arr.entries()) {
    console.log( idx + ': ' + el );
}
```

Comment: Yes @GalMargalit, I read it carefully. I agree that the `for each...in` is deprecated (first point), but I did not write about it... I wrote that "Destructuring `for...in` is deprecated. Use `for...of` instead." (second point): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#Statements Do you agree with me @GalMargalit?

Comment: Haha you are right, I didn't read carefully! True, I was basically thinking the same thing and thought you are referring to another.

Answer (score 13):

The **`for...in`** statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in an arbitrary order.
Enumerable properties are those properties whose internal [[Enumerable]] flag is set to true, hence if there is any enumerable property in the prototype chain, the `for...in` loop will iterate on those as well.

The **`for...of`** statement iterates over data that iterable object defines to be iterated over.

**Example:**

```
Object.prototype.objCustom = function() {}; 
Array.prototype.arrCustom = function() {};

let iterable = [3, 5, 7];

for (let i in iterable) {
  console.log(i); // logs: 0, 1, 2, "arrCustom", "objCustom"
}

for (let i in iterable) {
  if (iterable.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    console.log(i); // logs: 0, 1, 2,
  }
}

for (let i of iterable) {
  console.log(i); // logs: 3, 5, 7
}
```

Like earlier, you can skip adding `hasOwnProperty` in `for...of` loops.

Answer (score 10):

The for-in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in arbitrary order.

The loop will iterate over all enumerable properties of the object itself and those the object inherits from its constructor's prototype

You can think of it as "for in" basically iterates and list out all the keys.

```
var str = 'abc';
var arrForOf = [];
var arrForIn = [];

for(value of str){
  arrForOf.push(value);
}

for(value in str){
  arrForIn.push(value);
}

console.log(arrForOf); 
// ["a", "b", "c"]
console.log(arrForIn); 
// ["0", "1", "2", "formatUnicorn", "truncate", "splitOnLast", "contains"]
```

Comment: `for in ` will only show the keys if they are added by us, it's not gonna show formatUnicorn

Comment: "formatUnicorn", "truncate", "splitOnLast", "contains" print out because stackoverflow override `String.prototype`.

Answer (score 10):

There are some already defined data types which allows us to iterate over them easily e.g Array, Map, String Objects

Normal **for in** iterates over the iterator and in response provides us with the keys that are in the order of insertion as shown in below example.

```
  const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
   for(let number in number) {
     console.log(number);
   }

   // result: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Now if we try same with **for of**, then in response it provides us with the values not the keys. e.g

```
  const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
   for(let numbers of numbers) {
    console.log(number);
  }

  // result: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

So looking at both of the iterators we can easily differentiate the difference between both of them.

> Note:- **For of** only works with the Symbol.iterator

So if we try to iterate over normal object, then it will give us an error e.g-

```
const Room = {
   area: 1000,
   height: 7,
   floor: 2
 }

for(let prop in Room) {
 console.log(prop);
 } 

// Result area, height, floor

for(let prop of Room) {
  console.log(prop);
 }
```

> Room is not iterable

Now for iterating over we need to define an ES6 Symbol.iterator e.g

```
  const Room= {
    area: 1000, height: 7, floor: 2,
   [Symbol.iterator]: function* (){
    yield this.area;
    yield this.height;
    yield this.floors;
  }
}


for(let prop of Room) {
  console.log(prop);
 } 

//Result 1000, 7, 2
```

This is the difference between **For in** and **For of**. Hope that it might clear the difference.

Comment: while you are defining Symbol.iterator, why have you used function* and not function, what is the difference and what is the point of using function* here, please explain.

Comment: function* defines a generator function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

Answer (score 9):

Just remember that `for in` is used for objects, while `for of` is used for arrays, strings, etc.

However, you don't even need to use `for in`. You can always use `for of` instead:

```
const person = {name: 'John', age: 31};

for (let key in person) {
   console.log(key, ': ', person[key]);  // name: John
}                                        // age: 31

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(person)) {
   console.log(key, ': ', value); // The same output
}
```

Answer (score 7):

## The `for-in` loop

`for-in` loop is used to traverse through enumerable properties of a collection, **in an arbitrary order**. A collection is a container type object whose items can be using an index or a key.

```js
var myObject = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
var myArray = [1, 2, 3];
var myString = "123";

console.log( myObject[ 'a' ], myArray[ 1 ], myString[ 2 ] );
```

`for-in` loop extracts the **enumerable** properties (**keys**) of a collection **all at once** and iterates over it one at a time. An enumerable property is the property of a collection that can appear in `for-in` loop.

By default, all properties of an Array and Object appear in `for-in` loop. However, we can use [**Object.defineProperty**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) method to manually configure the properties of a collection.

```js
var myObject = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
var myArray = [1, 2, 3];

Object.defineProperty( myObject, 'd', { value: 4, enumerable: false } );
Object.defineProperty( myArray, 3, { value: 4, enumerable: false } );

for( var i in myObject ){ console.log( 'myObject:i =>', i ); }
for( var i in myArray ){ console.log( 'myArray:i  =>', i ); }
```

In the above example, the property `d` of the `myObject` and the index `3` of `myArray` does not appear in `for-in` loop because they are configured with `enumerable: false`.

There are few issues with `for-in` loops. In the case of Arrays, `for-in` loop will also consider `methods` added on the array using `myArray.someMethod = f` syntax, however, `myArray.length` remains `4`.

## The `for-of` loop

It is a misconception that `for-of` loop iterate over the values of a collection. `for-of` loop iterates over an `Iterable` object. An iterable is an object that has the method with the name `Symbol.iterator` directly on it one on one of its prototypes.

`Symbol.iterator` method should return an [**Iterator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Iterators). An iterator is an object which has a `next` method. This method when called return `value` and `done` properties.

When we iterate an **iterable** object using `for-of` loop, the `Symbol.iterator` the method will be called once get an **iterator** object. For every iteration of `for-of` loop, `next` method of this iterator object will be called until `done` returned by the `next()` call returns false. The value received by the `for-of` loop for every iteration if the `value` property returned by the `next()` call.

```js
var myObject = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };

// make `myObject` iterable by adding `Symbol.iterator` function directlty on it
myObject[ Symbol.iterator ] = function(){
  console.log( `LOG: called 'Symbol.iterator' method` );
  var _myObject = this; // `this` points to `myObject`
  
  // return an iterator object
  return {
    keys: Object.keys( _myObject ), 
    current: 0,
    next: function() {
      console.log( `LOG: called 'next' method: index ${ this.current }` );
      
      if( this.current === this.keys.length ){
        return { done: true, value: null }; // Here, `value` is ignored by `for-of` loop
      } else {
        return { done: false, value: _myObject[ this.keys[ this.current++ ] ] };
      }
    }
  };
}

// use `for-of` loop on `myObject` iterable
for( let value of myObject ) {
  console.log( 'myObject: value => ', value );
}
```

The `for-of` loop is new in ES6 and so are the **Iterable** and **Iterables**. The `Array` constructor type has `Symbol.iterator` method on its prototype. The `Object` constructor sadly doesn't have it but `Object.keys()`, `Object.values()` and `Object.entries()` methods return an iterable (*you can use `console.dir(obj)` to check prototype methods*). The benefit of the `for-of` loop is that any object can be made iterable, even your custom `Dog` and `Animal` classes.

The easy way to make an object iterable is by implementing [**ES6 Generator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) instead of custom iterator implementation.

Unlike `for-in`, `for-of` loop can wait for an async task to complete in each iteration. This is achieved using `await` keyword after `for` statement [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of).

Another great thing about `for-of` loop is that it has Unicode support. According to ES6 specifications, strings are stored with UTF-16 encoding. Hence, each character can take either `16-bit` or `32-bit`. Traditionally, strings were stored with UCS-2 encoding which has supports for characters that can be stored within `16 bits` only.

Hence, `String.length` returns number of `16-bit` blocks in a string. Modern characters like an Emoji character takes 32 bits. Hence, this character would return `length` of 2. `for-in` loop iterates over `16-bit` blocks and returns the wrong `index`. However, `for-of` loop iterates over the individual character based on UTF-16 specifications.

```js
var emoji = "";

console.log( 'emoji.length', emoji.length );

for( var index in emoji ){ console.log( 'for-in: emoji.character', emoji[index] ); }
for( var character of emoji ){ console.log( 'for-of: emoji.character', character ); }
```

Answer (score 6):

**for...of** loop works only with iterable objects. In JavaScript, iterables are objects which can be looped over.

String, Array, TypedArray, Map, and Set are all built-in iterables, because each of their prototype objects implements an @@iterator method. So, for...of loop works on the mentioned object types.

Object in JavaScript is not iterable by default. So, for...of loop does not work on objects.

In simple words, for...of works with strings and arrays but not with objects.

**for...in** works with those properties whose enumerable flag is set to true.

Enumerable flag for properties created via simple assignment or property initializer are by default true.
Enumerable flag for properties created via Object.defineProperty are by default false.

Here is a more detailed post with examples: https://dev.to/swastikyadav/difference-between-forof-and-forin-loop-in-javascript-j2o

Answer (score 4):

In simple terms forIN iterates over the KEYS IN the array(index)/object(key),
whereas forOF iterates over the VALUES OF the array(value).

Answer (score 3):

A see a lot of good answers, but I decide to put my 5 cents just to have good example:

## For in loop

iterates over all **enumerable props**

```js
let nodes = document.documentElement.childNodes;

for (var key in nodes) {
  console.log( key );
}
```

## For of loop

iterates over all **iterable values**

```js
let nodes = document.documentElement.childNodes;

for (var node of nodes) {
  console.log( node.toString() );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When I first started out learning the **for in** and **of loop**, I was confused with my output too, but with a couple of research and understanding you can think of the individual loop like the following : 
 The

1. ***for...in*** ***loop*** returns the **indexes** of the individual property and has *no effect* of impact on the *property's value*, it loops and returns information on the **property** and not the **value**.
   E.g

`let profile = {
    name : "Naphtali",
    age : 24,
    favCar : "Mustang",
    favDrink : "Baileys"
    }`

The above code is just creating an **object** called **profile**, we'll use it for *both our examples*, so, don't be confused when you see the *profile object* on an example, just know it was created.

> So now let us use the ***for...in loop*** below

```
for(let myIndex in profile){
    console.log(`The index of my object property is ${myIndex}`)
}
 // Outputs : 
        The index of my object property is 0
        The index of my object property is 1
        The index of my object property is 2
        The index of my object property is 3
```

> Now Reason for the output being that we have **Four(4)** properties in our **profile** object and indexing as we all know starts from ***0...n***, so, we get the index of properties ***0,1,2,3*** since we are working with the ***for..in*** loop.

2. **for...of loop*** can return either **the property**, **value** *or* **both**, Let's take a look at how.
   In javaScript, we can't loop through objects normally as we would on arrays, so, there are a few elements we can use to access either of our choices from an object.

   - **Object.keys**(*object-name-goes-here*)  >>> Returns the **keys** or **properties** of an object.
   - **Object.values**(*object-name-goes-here*)  >>> Returns the **values** of an object.
   - **Object.entries**(*object-name-goes-here*)  >>> Returns **both** the **keys** and **values** of an object.

---

Below are examples of their usage, *pay attention to Object.entries()* :

```
Step One: Convert the object to get either its key, value, or both.
Step Two: loop through.


// Getting the keys/property

   Step One: let myKeys = ***Object.keys(profile)***
   Step Two: for(let keys of myKeys){
             console.log(`The key of my object property is ${keys}`)
           }

// Getting the values of the property

    Step One: let myValues = ***Object.values(profile)***
    Step Two : for(let values of myValues){
                 console.log(`The value of my object property is ${values}`)
               }
```

> When using ***Object.entries()*** have it that you are calling two entries on the object, *i.e* the keys and values. You can call both by either of the entry. Example Below.

```
Step One: Convert the object to entries, using ***Object.entries(object-name)***
Step Two: **Destructure** the ***entries object which carries the keys and values*** 
like so **[keys, values]**, by so doing, you have access to either or both content.


    // Getting the keys/property

       Step One: let myKeysEntry = ***Object.entries(profile)***
       Step Two: for(let [keys, values] of myKeysEntry){
                 console.log(`The key of my object property is ${keys}`)
               }

    // Getting the values of the property

        Step One: let myValuesEntry = ***Object.entries(profile)***
        Step Two : for(let [keys, values] of myValuesEntry){
                     console.log(`The value of my object property is ${values}`)
                   }

    // Getting both keys and values

        Step One: let myBothEntry = ***Object.entries(profile)***
        Step Two : for(let [keys, values] of myBothEntry){
                     console.log(`The keys of my object is ${keys} and its value 
is ${values}`)
                   }
```

> Make comments on unclear parts section(s).

Comment: The very first line you mentioned is wrong. 

You mentioned >> "for...in loop returns the indexes of the individual property".

Actually in terms of Object, (for . . . in) returns the object key. Also, we can not perform for . . . of on object.

We can perform (for . . in) and (for  . . . of) on Array.

Answer (score 2):

Everybody did explain why this problem occurs, but it's still very easy to forget about it and then scratching your head why you got wrong results. Especially when you're working on big sets of data when the results seem to be fine at first glance.

Using `Object.entries` you ensure to go trough all properties:

```
var arr = [3, 5, 7];
arr.foo = "hello";

for ( var [key, val] of Object.entries( arr ) ) {
   console.log( val );
}

/* Result:

3
5
7
hello

*/
```

Answer (score -1):

Unique data constructors like this are usually used for `obfuscators` or alternatively to create `<cencored>`. brrr

```js
var arr = [3, 5, 7];
arr.foo = "hello";

console.log(typeof arr) // object
console.log(Object.keys(arr)) // ["0", "1", "2", "foo"]
console.log(Object.values(arr)) // ["3", "5", "7", "hello"]
// console.log(Object.entries(arr))
for (var index in arr) { 
  console.log(index); // logs "0", "1", "2", "foo"
}
for (var value of arr) {
  console.log(value); // logs "3", "5", "7"
}
for (var objValue of Object.values(arr)) {
  console.log(objValue); // logs "3", "5", "7", "hello"
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Simple answer is for..of you can use async inside it while for..in does not.