# JS Error with for(var key of...)

Tags: javascript

I have some code that I have been using in an application for some time now where all of our internal users are using firefox for running the app. There are a few people wanting to run IE and there is a block of code that I believe is hitting an error and I don't know exactly why..

```
// Given a field name, check to see if its in our output. If so, return the formatted link
function createLink(field, val) {

    var output = {
        'ntid': 'https://web.internal/profile/' + val,
        'email': 'mailTo:' + val
    };

    for (var key of Object.keys(output)){
        if (field.toLowerCase().includes(key)){
            return `<a href="${output[key]}" target="_blank">${val}</a>`;
        }
    }

    return val;
}
```

In IE 11, I get a console error `SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'` which refers to the line `for (var key of Object.keys(output)){`.

Is this not supported in `IE11` or is there some type of syntax that FF handles correctly that IE doesn't?

Comment: `for of ` doesnt work in IE you have to use normal `for` loop with btw is more efficient `for(var i =0 ;` <- this is expected ;

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the "for...of", try a "for...in" which is supported by every browser for a long time now.  Syntax is exactly the same.

(There is a difference between them but I guess in your case it's not relevant...  More about this here: [What is the difference between ( for... in ) and ( for... of ) in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285897/what-is-the-difference-between-for-in-and-for-of-in-javascript) )

Comment: I tried this simple change and got `Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'`

Comment: for... of is smiliar to for... each of AS3/ES4, except that for... each iterates values of object-kind value, and for... of uses a symbol inside object property, in order to iterate values of collections (but all values from the properties, they've to be values).

Comment: @handoncloud - Any chance you could share what the compatible code would be for this example? Sounds like I have more than one issue in this case after swapping `of` for `in`.

Comment: @SBB You could try `var i, key, keys = Object.keys(output); for ( i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i ) key = keys[i]...; `, but this won't be exactly the same as for... of, because it uses a symbol reserved as property in the loop object.

Comment: The "includes" thing is an independent problem, it's because IE is not ES6 compliant.  Try indexOf()...

Comment: ^ Yeah, for... in would also work, but you need to take the property value  from the key you receive too.

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of the "for...of", try a "for...in" which is supported by
>   every browser for a long time now. Syntax is exactly the same.

Not entirely:

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of