# Typescript infers incorrect type: TS2339 property 'selected' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: typescript

In the following example Typescript infers a type string for the inner element type of the values array. Then it complains that string doesn't have the property "selected".

```
let item = { values: [{selected: "123"}]}

for (let foobar in item.values) {
    if (foobar.selected === '123') {
        console.log('found');
    }
}
```

[image: error message image]

When running the example in the typescript playground I get the above error:
[playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20item%20%3D%20%7B%20values%3A%20%5B%7Bselected%3A%20%22123%22%7D%5D%7D%0A%0Afor%20(let%20foobar%20in%20item.values)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(foobar.selected%20%3D%3D%3D%20'123')%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('found')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want `for..of` instead of `for..in`, more here: [What is the difference between ( for... in ) and ( for... of ) in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285897/what-is-the-difference-between-for-in-and-for-of-in-javascript)

Comment: Your answer could be a little more helpful if you also just told the OP that foobar gets the string `"0"` as its value.

Comment: Ah that's surprising. I come from a Java background and wasn't aware of the difference.