# Angular 2 HTTP json request giving me a weird response when trying to parse result

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular-http

So I have the http.get call working and can correctly grab data from the request:

```
this.http.get('https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/xx67-kt59.json').subscribe(data => {
      // Read the result field from the JSON response.
      console.log(data);

  for (let x in data) {
    console.log(x);
  }
});
```

The console.log(data) line works successfully, it prints me out an array of th e items from the request.

The trouble I'm having is when I try and iterate through each individually item in the JSON array.

```
for (let x in data) {
   console.log(x);
}
```

Just prints me out the index/number of the item in the JSON object. Even if I try x["prop name"], it still fails.

Even the following doesn't work:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
```

My goal is to eventually map these to a class I'd define and populate an array variable with that data.

Am I being stupid in how I'd reference the JSON property for each item?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285897/what-is-the-difference-between-for-in-and-for-of-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to iterate over an `Array` you should use the `for of` construct.

```
for (let x of data) { 
  // `x` is an item from the array
}
```

The `for in` construct iterates over the *keys* of an object. In your case those are the array indexes.

Comment: Wow, did not know that, thanks! I tried it but now it's giving me an error saying "Type OBJECT is not an array type or a String type". Does this mean I have to JSON.stringify it? I thought Angular returned JSON in it's HTTP calls.

I had just tried it and it seems like it's not printing out every.single.character individually.

Comment: If you are using `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'`, you don't have to parse the response body to JSON. Can you please post more of your code?

Comment: I was able to figure it out. There was also something screwy with my TSlint file so it kept giving me an error when there was none. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `for (let x of data)` instead of `for (let x in data)`.