# Unable to iterate throug JS array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, object

When i see my **book** object in console it shows array but when i try to iterate it does not iterartes in loop.

```
console.log(book);// logs array of length 6
console.log(typeof book);// logs -> object
console.log(book.length);// logs 0

//this for loop does not iterates.

for(let i of book)
        {

           //logic
        }
```

**Please help me how to iterate?**
**my book object looks like below on console.**

[image: my book object looks like below on console.]

Comment: Were missing some details here, how are you getting book, could you show more of the process.?  Using a hunch, I've a feeling it's an async issue..

Comment: i am passing it in function. this above code is of the function.

Comment: Actualyy i am writing an agular 2 pipe in which i ma getting this book object.

Comment: That's not really helping, could you show the code were you getting `book`, if this is an Ajax request, chances are your running into an `async` issue.

Comment: How is `book.length` zero? Did you not just say that the array has 6 elements in it?

Comment: Did you try with `for(let i in book)`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285897/what-is-the-difference-between-for-in-and-for-of-in-javascript

Comment: Is it throwing any error?

Comment: @tuna  In modern JS, best stay away from `in` unless you want to mess about with `hasOwnProperty`.   `of` works with any itterable in a consistent way.

Comment: @AbhayKumar, If you feed Angular pipe with Async data, initially it returns nothing on page load as there's no data. So your book array could be empty. Once it gets the data, It processes.

Comment: Why do you expect the loop to iterate over an *empty* array?! Logically it iterates zero times over an array with zero elements.

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for your help issue stands resolved :)

Comment: I was creating a custom pipe for ngFor and was passing async object i made my PIPE impure and it started getting the array properly.

Answer (score -3):

let i of book is wrong. Since it is an array of object, try to do below.

```
  book.forEach( function (bookItem)
{
    Your logic
});
```

Comment: No it should be `of`

Comment: for/in is for objects for/of works for Arrays

Comment: It is of in *ngFor, in typescript / js, it is "in" only

Comment: What does the above mean?

Comment: same issue with in.

Comment: @AbhayKumar  Indeed it will be, as this code you have shown is not were the problem is.  Please note, in Chrome the console.log can be miss-leading, this is because when console logging objects it takes a reference to the object  (IOW: a live reference).  So if you have an `async` issues it might look correct, but that's only because of the time delay of you (the user), clicking the live reference to get the latest value.

Comment: @keith how to iterate async array then?

Comment: @AbhayKumar, Whatever Keith is saying is absolutely true. Angular updates values displayed in the console. Ever faced this with Angular. You better give us some more info on your problem.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: @AbhayKumar, I don't think you need to do anything specifically to iterate asnyc array other than using async pipe. https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: I downvoted cause this code is more worse than the OPs code, and it is not solving anything.

Comment: Its fine, but since console log was able to print the object, but if the object could not be iterated, there will be no problem with the async call for sure. It is the problem with the iteration logic.

Comment: @AmareshC. thanks you are right. I made my PIPE impure #async #stateful :).