# Why can't I assign new value to variable inside a block?

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop, if-statement

Below I have two examples of code. They are the same except I change the value of `w` at the beginning. In either example, `m` has a value. All I'm trying to do is set `x = m`. Why can I do this in the first but not the second? I'm testing this in the console in Chrome (68.0.3440.84)

**This works (m = 100| x = 100)**

```js
    var c = [],
     w="word",
     x = 0;
        for (l=0; l<w.length; l++){
         c.push(w.charCodeAt(l));
        }
    
    for (i in c) {
     if (c.length > 0) {
            var m = c[1];
            if (m > Math.min(m, c[i])) {
                m = Math.min(m, c[i]);
       x = m; 
       console.log(x);
            } 
        }
    }
```

**This does not work (m = 97| x = 0):**

```js
    var c = [],
     w="cancel",
     x = 0;
        for (l=0; l<w.length; l++){
         c.push(w.charCodeAt(l));
        }
    
    for (i in c) {
     if (c.length > 0) {
            var m = c[1];
            if (m > Math.min(m, c[i])) {
                m = Math.min(m, c[i]);
       x = m; //why cant I set this?
       console.log(x);
            } 
        }
    }
```

There is more I want to do but in my process of figuring out this learning problem I have I have been unable to set this variable `x` reliably and I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: `for..in` is for iterating over object properties, not for arrays. For those, use `for..of`.

Comment: FYI: `for/in` loops should be used on Objects only, not Arrays as they iterate all the properties of the array. For Arrays, use `.forEach()`.

Comment: For starters, you should be using `for...of` with arrays, not `for...in` [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285897/what-is-the-difference-between-for-in-and-for-of-in-javascript). I'm not sure if that is the cause of your issue, but it certainly doesn't help

Comment: I will take that advice and re-write what I'm doing. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

It is because `if (m > Math.min(m, c[i]))` condition is never met. In your example both `m` and `Math.min(m, c[i])` have the same value. Replacing `>` with `>=` seems to be fixing your issue. Or moving `console.log` outside `if` statement - depending on what you're actually trying to achieve.

```js
var c = [],
  w = "cancel",
  x = 0;
for (l = 0; l < w.length; l++) {
  c.push(w.charCodeAt(l));
}

for (i in c) {
  if (c.length > 0) {
    var m = c[1];
    if (m >= Math.min(m, c[i])) { // because m > Math.min(m, c[i]) would return false
      m = Math.min(m, c[i]);
      x = m
      console.log(x);
    }
  }
}
```