# Vue directive v-for="thing in collection" vs "thing of collection"

Tags: javascript, for-loop, vue.js, ecmascript-6

In the official Vue.js documentation, all of the examples for the [v-for directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) have the format:

```
v-for="thing in collection"
```

where `collection` includes arrays and objects. Further, the documentation states:

> You can also use `of` as the delimiter instead of `in`, so that it is closer to JavaScript’s syntax for iterators.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285897/what-is-the-difference-between-for-in-and-for-of-in-javascript) explains the difference between `for..in` and `for..of` loops in vanilla JavaScript. As I understood it, `for..in` is used to loop over an object's properties and `for..of` is used to loop over an iterable's elements.

**My question is**, do `of` and `in` carry the same meaning in Vue as they do in vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: did you try with any sample data and check in vanilla and vuejs both ? if yes please share?

Comment: The [answer is here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2410), and this article about Vue v3 and how it will support new data types for `v-for` [Article](https://medium.com/the-vue-point/plans-for-the-next-iteration-of-vue-js-777ffea6fabf)

Answer (score 14):

**They do not**

In Vue.js, `for..of` and `for..in` are equivalent and interchangeable. Iterating in Vue.js is very flexible and can handle a wide variety of objects and types (Even integers! Take note, TC39!).

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/list.html

The following is valid Vue.js code:

```html
<p v-for="x of {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}">{{x}}</p>
<p v-for="x in {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}">{{x}}</p>
  
<p v-for="x of [1, 2, 3]">{{x}}</p>
<p v-for="x in [1, 2, 3]">{{x}}</p>
```

All of these will print out `1`, `2`, `3`.

In plain JavaScript, however, there is a difference between `for..of` and `for..in`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

The important difference is that `for..of` will iterate over **iterable objects**, where `for..in` will iterate over **enumerable properties**.

```js
for (const x of {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}) {console.log(x);} // TypeError ... is not iterable
for (const x in {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}) {console.log(x);} // Prints a b c

for (const x of [1, 2, 3]) {console.log(x);} // Prints 1 2 3
for (const x in [1, 2, 3]) {console.log(x);} // Prints 0 1 2 (the indexes)
```

As you can see, they behave very differently.

Even what might look like the same code (`for..in {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}`) will yield different results in Vue.js and plain JavaScript, one will print `1`, `2`, `3`, the other `a`, `b`, `c`.