# Replace Words Jquery, only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript but everytime i save the language on my site that add
on the final another "0" example "italiano" if i save my profile much more one time the script add another "0" like that "Italianoo" and if i save again "Italianooo"

How y can fix that ? also without the dictionary

Many thanks

```js
var dictionary = {
  "Afrikanns": "Africano",
  "Albanian": "Albanese",
  "Arabic": "Arabo",
  "Armeno": "Armenian",
  "Basque": "Basco",
  "Bengali": "Bengalese",
  "Bielorussian": "Bielorusso",
  "Bulgarian": "Bulgaro",
  "Catalan": "Catalano",
  "Cambodian": "Cambogiano",
  "Czech": "Ceco",
  "Cinese": "Cinese",
  "Korean": "Coreano",
  "Croatian": "Croato",
  "Danish": "Danese",
  "Hebrew": "Ebraico",
  "Estonian": "Estone",
  "Fijan": "Fiji",
  "Finnish": "Finlandese",
  "French": "Francese",
  "Georgian": "Georgiano",
  "Japanese": "Giapponese",
  "Javanese": "Giavanese",
  "Greek": "Greco",
  "Gujarati": "Gujarati",
  "Hindi": "Indiano",
  "English": "Inglese",
  "Indonesian": "Indonesiano",
  "Irish": "Irlandese",
  "Icelandic": "Islandese",
  "Italian": "Italiano",
  "Latin": "Latino",
  "Latvian": "Lettone",
  "Lithuanian": "Lituano",
  "Macedonian": "Macedone",
  "Malayalam": "Malayalam",
  "Maltese": "Malese",
  "Maori": "Maori",
  "Marathi": "Marathi",
  "Mongolian": "Mongolo",
  "Nepali": "Nepalese",
  "Norwegian": "Norvegese",
  "Dutch": "Olandese",
  "Persian": "Persiano",
  "Polish": "Polacco",
  "Portoguese": "Portoghese",
  "Punjabi": "Punjabi",
  "Quechua": "Quechua",
  "Romanian": "Rumeno",
  "Russian": "Russo",
  "Samoan": "Samoan",
  "Serbian": "Serbo",
  "Slovak": "Slovacco",
  "Slovenian": "Sloveno",
  "Spanish": "Spagnolo",
  "Swedish": "Svedese",
  "Swahili": "Swahili",
  "Thai": "Tailandese",
  "Tamil": "Tamil",
  "Tatar": "Tatar",
  "German": "Tedesco",
  "Telugu": "Telugu",
  "Tibetan": "Tibetano",
  "Tonga": "Tonga",
  "Turkish": "Turco",
  "Ukranian": "Ucraino",
  "Hungarian": "Ungherese",
  "Urdu": "Urdu",
  "Uzbek": "Uzbeko",
  "Vietnamese": "Vietnamita",
  "Welsh": "Welsh",
  "Xhosa": "Xhosa"
};

jQuery(".upme-field-value > span").each(function() {
  for (var ptrn in dictionary) {
    jQuery(this).text(jQuery(this).text().replace(new RegExp(ptrn, "g"), dictionary[ptrn]));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="upme-field-value">
  <span>Italian</span>
</div>
```

Comment: avoid using `for .. in` on objects. Use `for .. of` instead or `Object.entries` or `Object.values` or `Object.keys`. Your code seems to work properly in the above snippet anyway, though the behavior you describe is really making me thing that the issue is just the for .. in. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285897/what-is-the-difference-between-for-in-and-for-of-statements-in-jav

Comment: It works in the snippet because the function is only executed once. If you do it multiple times you get `Italianooooo` etc. @Alecs how are you calling this logic, and on exactly what HTML?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ops, I've lost the part where he said that he is running the code multiple times.

Comment: That happens only with the languages with have last the "ano" "Catalano", "Africano", "Italiano" i dont know way...I using UPME plugin in wordpress and when i change my profile etc ...i use the "jQuery(document).ready(function () {"

Comment: I think is better make the dictionary only if the Language is exactly, like that ? "/\ptrn\b/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for **word boundary** [`\b`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary)

```js
console.log("Italian".replace(/\bItalian\b/g, 'Italiano'))

console.log("Italiano".replace(/\bItalian\b/g, 'Italiano'))
```