# Making a for loop to calculate specific cells then writing result in the last cell in row

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to JS and I'm trying to learn for loops and in this case, I want to turn this into a for loop if possible. I want to calculate a static number string in cell 3, times the input number in cell 4, and output the result to a new cell 5 that has been created in the loop. Any help is much appreciated

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table");

var Row1 = table.rows[1],
    cell1 = Row1.insertCell(5);
var Row2 = table.rows[2],
    cell2 = Row2.insertCell(5);
var Row3 = table.rows[3],
    cell3 = Row3.insertCell(5);
var Row4 = table.rows[4],
    cell4 = Row4.insertCell(5);
var Row5 = table.rows[5],
    cell5 = Row5.insertCell(5);
var Row6 = table.rows[6],
    cell6 = Row6.insertCell(5);

var x1 = table.rows[1].cells[4].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
var y1 = table.rows[1].cells[3].innerHTML;
    cell1.innerHTML = y1 * x1;
var x2 = table.rows[2].cells[4].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
var y2 = table.rows[2].cells[3].innerHTML;
    cell2.innerHTML = y2 * x2;
var x3 = table.rows[3].cells[4].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
var y3 = table.rows[3].cells[3].innerHTML;
    cell3.innerHTML = y3 * x3;
var x4 = table.rows[4].cells[4].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
var y4 = table.rows[4].cells[3].innerHTML;
    cell4.innerHTML = y4 * x4;
var x5 = table.rows[5].cells[4].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
var y5 = table.rows[5].cells[3].innerHTML;
    cell5.innerHTML = y5 * x5;
var x6 = table.rows[6].cells[4].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
var y6 = table.rows[6].cells[3].innerHTML;
    cell6.innerHTML = y6 * x6;
```

Comment: This confuses me a bit, sorry :p Do you have any accompanying HTML? Might help to see what we're working with.

Comment: Newest edit removed the earlier added HTML, look into the revisions for clarity. The OP seems to have copy-pasted his newest JS-code over all the previous code (including the HTML), without re-adding the newest HTML-code, without checking what he is actually overriding. Quite questionable move, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for-loops like the one given below. Looks like you are operating on numbers, so I have added a `+` in front of `x1`'s and `y1`'s assignment to implicitly type-cast them to numbers.

```js
for(var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
  var firstRow = table.rows[i], cell = firstRow.insertCell(5);
  var x1 = +table.rows[i].cells[4].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  var y1 = +table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML;
  cell.innerHTML = y1 * x1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These don't need to be in functions but just to make it easier to read

```
function createCells() {
  cells = []
  for (let i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    var cells[i] = table.rows[i].insertCell(5)
  }
}

function calculate() {
  for
  let (i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    var x = table.rows[i].cells[4].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
    var y = table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML;
    cells[i].innerHTML = (y * x);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A short answer using a simple *for*-loop is this:

1. Loop through every row
2. For each row, multiply quantity with price
3. Output total in same row

Since we basically always want to have a "total"-field in every row, we can add it in the HTML directly.
And since we know the position of the price-element and quantity-element, we can access them using fixed values as indices.

```js
var rows = document.querySelectorAll("#pricetable tbody tr");
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) {
  var price = rows[i].children[3].innerHTML;
  var quantity = rows[i].children[4].children[0].value;
  var total = price * quantity; // Implicit type-casting to numbers
  rows[i].children[5].innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<table id="pricetable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Brand</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>23456789</td>
      <td>Phone</td>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>6500</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" size="3" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>22256289</td>
      <td>Phone</td>
      <td>Samsung</td>
      <td>6200</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" size="3" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>24444343</td>
      <td>Phone</td>
      <td>Huawei</td>
      <td>4200</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" size="3" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>19856639</td>
      <td>Tablet</td>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>4000</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" size="3" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>39856639</td>
      <td>Tablet</td>
      <td>Samsung</td>
      <td>2800</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" size="3" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12349862</td>
      <td>Tablet</td>
      <td>Huawei</td>
      <td>3500</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" size="3" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Note:** When changing the position of those elements (e.g. by add a new column infront of them), their index would shift. That would make you have to update the indices in the JS-file manually.
You can make this easier for yourself by using this simple "trick":
Add specific classes to the elements (e.g. `.price`, `.quantity`, `.total`), allowing you to easily find them using [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).

**Note:** The script only runs once, the first time the page is loaded. That means, inputting a different quantity won't update the "total"-field. For that, we need an [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

**Another approach**
By observing the for-loop, we can see:

- We access only one row for each iteration
- The order in which we access each row is irrelevant

Since both these points are checked, we can use a [*for...of*-loop](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) (also called *foreach*-loop or *enhanced for*-loop). A *for...of*-loop is (in my opinion) easier to read, and tells what we checked using the list above by itself.
**Note:** Be wary of the [difference of the for...of-loop and the for...in-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285897/what-is-the-difference-between-for-in-and-for-of-statements-in-jav).

Now, we could calculate the total right then and there in the loop, but thinking ahead, we want to perform the *same* calculation again when inputting a new quantity-value. We can reduce the duplicate code by making the calculation a [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) `updateRowTotal()`, making the code easier to debug *and* understand.

To actually update the total when entering a new quantity-value, we can use an [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) that calls a function automatically when a new value is entered into the `<input>`-field (by calling `updateRowTotal(evt.target.closest("tr"))`).

```js
function clamp(min, value, max) {
  return Math.max(min, Math.min(value, max));
}

for (let row of document.querySelectorAll("#pricetable tbody tr")) {
  updateRowTotal(row);
  row.querySelector("input.quantity").addEventListener("input", evt => {
    // Add '/*' before this comment to "remove" this extra part
    // The 5 lines below are to clamp 'value' between 'min' and 'max'
    let min = parseInt(evt.target.getAttribute("min"));
    let max = parseInt(evt.target.getAttribute("max"));
    if (isNaN(min)) min = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER;
    if (isNaN(max)) max = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
    evt.target.value = clamp(min, evt.target.value, max);
    // */
    updateRowTotal(evt.target.closest("tr"));
  });
}

function updateRowTotal(row) {
  row.querySelector(".total").innerHTML = row.querySelector(".price").innerHTML * row.querySelector(".quantity").value;
}
```

```html
<table id="pricetable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Row-Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="price">6500</td>
      <td>
        <input class="quantity" type="number" min="0" max="999" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td class="total"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="price">6200</td>
      <td>
        <input class="quantity" type="number" min="0" max="999" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td class="total"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="price">4200</td>
      <td>
        <input class="quantity" type="number" min="0" max="999" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td class="total"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="price">4000</td>
      <td>
        <input class="quantity" type="number" min="0" max="999" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td class="total"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="price">2800</td>
      <td>
        <input class="quantity" type="number" min="0" max="999" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td class="total"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="price">3500</td>
      <td>
        <input class="quantity" type="number" min="0" max="999" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td class="total"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Sidenote**
Making the `<input>`-field of `type="number"` prevents any non-numeric character to be entered.
And since the `min`- and `max`-attributes only prevent form-submission, we have to code the value-clamping ourselves. This is easily done by reading the values of the attributes and clamping the value to their defined range. Note that we have added default values for both `min` and `max`, being the lower-most and upper-most [safe integer-value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).