# Accessing properties from object in `for`–`in` loop results in `undefined`

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, for-in-loop

I have these two classes:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(nodeId){
        this.nodeId = nodeId;
        this.adjacencies = [];
    }

    connectToNode(nodeToConnectTo){
        this.adjacencies.push(nodeToConnectTo);
    }
}

class Graph{
    constructor(nodes){
        this.nodes = nodes;
    }

    printGraph(){
        for (let node in this.nodes){
            console.log(node.nodeId);
        }
        
    }
}
```

I’m simply trying to call `printGraph` to print all the `nodeId`s this way:

```js
let node1 = new Node('1');
let node2 = new Node('2');
let node3 = new Node('3');
const arr = [node1, node2, node3];
let graph = new Graph(arr);

graph.printGraph();
```

But it’s printing `undefined`. I can’t seem to figure out why it isn’t simply printing the `nodeId`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between ( for... in ) and ( for... of ) statements in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285897/what-is-the-difference-between-for-in-and-for-of-statements-in-jav)

Comment: use `let node of this.nodes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using the wrong for loop.
Try changing it to:

```
printGraph(){
  for (let node of this.nodes){
    console.log(node.nodeId);
  }   
}
```

A for..of loop should loop over the node the way you want.

Result:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that you are using "for in" loop instead of "for of" to iterate over an array.

"for in" loop is used to iterate object properties

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're iterating over the properties of the array object by using the `in` keyword. For an array, this means you're iterating over the **indices (keys)**, namely 0, 1, 2 in your 3-member array. Those are strings, and don't have a `nodeId` property, so your output is `undefined`. You'll see these if you run `console.log(node, typeof node)` inside your current loop (staying with `in`).

If you use the `of` keyword in your for loop, you'll get the **values** of the array, namely the objects with 1, 2 and 3 as values for `nodeId`. So all you have to do is change the `in` to `of` and you'll have the output you're after.

Personally, I'd use this:

```js
printGraph(){
    const nodeIds = this.nodes.map(node => node.nodeId);
    console.log(nodeIds);
}
```

Comment: See [Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions) and [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score -1):

you need to print `console.log(node);`
cause you are looping trough `let node in this.nodes`

where `node` is an actual node from `this.nodes`

Comment: "_where `node` is an actual node from `this.nodes`_" No, it isn't. `node` in this case is the key/index of the element in the array.