# How does Object.entries() work? Unexpected console.log output

Tags: javascript

I've got object of objects:

```
let obj = {
  a: {
    af: {
      key: "k", val: "v"
    },
    bf: {
      key: "g", val: "h"
    }
  },
  b: {
    af: {
      key: "f", val: "w"
    },
    nf: {
      key: "u", val: "t"
    }
  }
};`
```

I'm trying to get an array of all values associated with `key` - in this case: `["k","g","f","u"]`
I tried to use `Object.entries()` in the for loop but I guess I do not understand how it works. I did simply as in docs:

```
for ([k,v] in Object.entries(obj)){
  console.log(k,v)
}
```

but my result is

> 0 undefined

> 1 undefined

which I completly do not understand. Could you please help me with explaining how this short code works?

```js
let obj = {a: {af: {key: "k", val: "v"}, bf: {key: "g", val: "h"}}, b: {af: {key: "f", val: "w"}, nf: {key: "u", val: "t"}}};

for ([k,v] in Object.entries(obj)){
  console.log(k,v)
}
```

Comment: It might make more sense if you write `for .. of` not `for .. in`. Also bear in mind that you want properties that are 3 levels deep, and your call to Object.entries is only digging out the props one level deep

Comment: `for (let [k,v] of Object.entries(obj)) {`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285897/what-is-the-difference-between-for-in-and-for-of-statements-in-jav https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-for-array-iteration-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.entries(obj)` returns an **array**. Each item in the array represents one property of the object expressed as an array containing the property name and the property value.

`x in someObject` gets the iterable property names of the object.

The property names in an array are the **numerical indexes**.

Hence your output:

```js
const [x,y] = "0";
console.log({x,y});
```

---

If you want to loop over the property values instead of the property names you need `of` (which loops over the **values**) not `in`.

```js
let obj = {a: {af: {key: "k", val: "v"}, bf: {key: "g", val: "h"}}, b: {af: {key: "f", val: "w"}, nf: {key: "u", val: "t"}}};

for ([k,v] of Object.entries(obj)){
  console.log(k,v)
}
```

However, looping over an array should probably be done using `forEach`  (or a traditional three-part for loop) instead, as it won't trip over unexpected enumerable properties that might be added to your array.

```js
let obj = {a: {af: {key: "k", val: "v"}, bf: {key: "g", val: "h"}}, b: {af: {key: "f", val: "w"}, nf: {key: "u", val: "t"}}};

Object.entries(obj).forEach( ([k,v]) => console.log({k,v}) );
```

Comment: Looping over an array should be done with `for … of` (which the OP tried but misspelled). Why do you recommend `forEach`?

Comment: To be honest I had no idea that there is both `for...in` and `for...of` loops. Absolutely fantastic lesson, thank you both!

Answer (score -1):

`for-in` loops over the keys of an object, it doesn't include the values. `Object.entries()` returns an iterator, not an object.

Use `forEach()` to iterate over its results:

```js
let obj = {a: {af: {key: "k", val: "v"}, bf: {key: "g", val: "h"}}, b: {af: {key: "f", val: "w"}, nf: {key: "u", val: "t"}}};

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => console.log(k, v));
```