# Why is the wrong type detected when using for (const var in Object.values){}?

Tags: typescript

In the following code, I would expect `val` to be detected as `MyType` in typescript. However, it is being detected as `string` which is the type of the key. Why?

```
type MyType = { one: string, two: string};

let sums: { [key: string]: MyType; } = {};


Object.values(sums).forEach(val => { 
console.log(value.one) // val is of type MyType 
});

for (const val in Object.values(sums)) {
     console.log(val). // why is val a string and not MyType?
}
```

Comment: I found out that using for ... of gives the expected result, but I still want to know why?

Comment: [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loops over the keys of an object. Object keys are always string (or symbols, but for in doesn't visit symbols). Object.values returns an array, so the keys of that array will be "0", "1", "2", etc.

Comment: This may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285897/what-is-the-difference-between-for-in-and-for-of-statements