# Javascript iterating through JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
  "comments": [
    {
      "created_utc": 1622513325,
      "text": "gdhg sgf sddsfsd fdsf"
    },
    {
      "created_utc": 1622513188,
      "text": "sfdg sgf fdgfdg"
    }
   ]
}
```

How would you iterate over each object to see the text?

Something like..?

```
  let data = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'comments.json'));
  let comments = JSON.parse(data);
  for(var i in comments){
    for(var j in i) {
      console.log("? " + j.text)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the available [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods) methods (both static and on prototype).

Comment: See [Why is using “for…in” for array iteration a bad idea?](/q/500504/4642212) and [What is the difference between ( for… in ) and ( for… of ) statements?](/q/29285897/4642212).

Comment: `for (var j of comments.comments)` -- no need for nested loops.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between ( for... in ) and ( for... of ) statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285897/what-is-the-difference-between-for-in-and-for-of-statements)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the structure of your JSON will always be a `comments` object on the first level, containing a list of elements with `created_utc` and `text`, you can do as easy as the following code.

You don't need to nest the cycle as you only want to iterate over one list, then read the items and directly access to the `text` field of each item.

```js
var jsonString = `{
  "comments": [
    {
      "created_utc": 1622513325,
      "text": "gdhg sgf sddsfsd fdsf"
    },
    {
      "created_utc": 1622513188,
      "text": "sfdg sgf fdgfdg"
    }
   ]
}`;

let comments = JSON.parse(jsonString).comments;

comments.forEach(comment => {
  console.log(comment.text);
});
```