# for-in loop doesn't execute class function

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop, for-of-loop

I have this `class Programmer extends Person` and this function is stored inside the class

```js
code () {console.log (`${this.name} is coding`)}
```

I then created an array outside of the class declaration

```js
const programmers = [new Programmer("dom", 56, 12), new Programmer("jeff", 24, 4)]
```

And also a function

```js
function developSoftware (programmers) {
    for (let programmer in programmers) {
        programmer.code()
    }
}
```

Why does the error `programmer.code is not a function` when I use a for-in loop instead of a for-of loop? what's the logic behind? I know that for arrays one should use a `for-of` loop

Also how do I format the code in StackOverflow such that the post shows line breaks in between the code?

```js
class Programmer
{
  code () {
    console.log (`${this.name} is coding`);
  }
}

const programmers = [new Programmer("dom", 56, 12), new Programmer("jeff", 24, 4)]

function developSoftware (programmers) {
  for (let programmer of programmers) {
    programmer.code()
  }
}

developSoftware(programmers);
```

Comment: I've added a snippet for you with the code you included, though I don't have the Person class that your class extends, so I removed that bit. There is no `.code() is undefined` error.

Comment: programmer doesnt extend person is this example.

Comment: there is no error because the code i posted uses the for-of loop, which i asked why the for-in loop doesnt work here

Comment: Oh I misunderstood your question then. `for in` gets the key, where `for of` gets the value. So in the loop `for(let p in programmers)`, `p` is the index of the array, so it would be `programmers[p]` in that case.

Comment: `for in` returns the enumerator of the item so 0, 1, 2, 3 `for of` retuns the item itself. If you use `for in` you still need to use that number as index to get the item out of the array.

Answer (score 1):

So Your question is **What is Difference `for..in` and `for..of`**:

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52854849/11359076):

1. `for..in` iterates over all enumerable property keys of an object
2. `for..of` iterates over the values of an iterable object. Examples of
   `iterable` objects are arrays, strings, and NodeLists.