# Comparing one value from two arrays if bigger then copying + combining into third array

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, google-apps-script, woocommerce

I'm trying to make a simple app to update prices in WooCommerce through the REST API.

I have arrayOne which has SKU + updated prices from my ERP

```
[
 {sku=PD-1000-B, price=9800.00},
 {sku=PD-1007-A, price=9678.16}
]
```

arrayTwo which has all products from woocommerce, SKU, id (which I need to get) and current price

```
[
 {sku=PD-1000-B, id=1622.0, price=8145.9},
 {sku=PD-1007-A, id=1624.0, price=9678.16}
]
```

I would like to compare arrayTwo with arrayOne, if price in arrayOne is bigger then with all coincidences combine and create new array. Something like this

```
[
 {sku=PD-1000-B, id=1622.0, price=9800.00}
]
```

Since the only bigger price is for PD-1000-B.

All I got so far is to create a new Set but that doesn't compare anything, the idea would be to reduce only to changes the amount to update.

EDIT: As of right now I'm merely replacing the price in arrayTwo with the one in arrayOne using this:

```
let set = new Set();
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    set.add(data[i]['sku'])
for (let i = 0; i < container.length; i++)
    if (set.has(container[i]['sku']))
        container[i]['price'] = data[i]['price'];
```

container is an empty variable I'm using to collect the data I get from WooCommerce as an array and data is a the array which contains the updated prices + sku.

Thank you.

Comment: Checkout my answer and let me know if it solves your issue +^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try it this way:

```js
var arrayOne = [
    {sku: 'PD-1000-B', price: 9800.00},
    {sku: 'PD-1007-A', price: 9678.16}
];

var arrayTwo = [
    {sku: 'PD-1000-B', id: 1622.0, price: 8145.9},
    {sku: 'PD-1007-A', id: 1624.0, price: 9678.16}
];

// convert the array into the object {sku1: {}, sku2: {}, ...}
var arrayOne_obj = {}
for (let obj of arrayOne)
    arrayOne_obj[obj.sku] = {'price': obj.price};

// convert the array into the object {sku1: {}, sku2: {}, ...}
var arrayTwo_obj = {}
for (let obj of arrayTwo)
    arrayTwo_obj[obj.sku] = {'price': obj.price, 'id': obj.id};

// loop through the 'sku'-subobjects of the 'arrayOne_obj' object
// compare its prices with prices of the same 'sku'-subobject of 'arrayTwo_obj',
// and make the output array
var output = [];
for (let sku in arrayOne_obj) {
    let subObjOne = arrayOne_obj[sku];
    let subObjTwo = arrayTwo_obj[sku];
    if (subObjOne.price > subObjTwo.price) {
        output.push({'sku':sku, 'id': subObjTwo.id, 'price':subObjOne.price});
    }  
}

console.log(output); // output [ {sku: 'PD-1000-B', id:1622.0, price:9800.00} ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This seems to de 100% exactly what I need, but I get an error:
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined" - Line 83
`if (subObjOne.price > subObjTwo.price) {`
 Which I find odd... I'm thinking maybe I haven't populated a dependant array yet?

https://pastebin.com/apsAQVg9

This is the entire code, I only changed the array names for the ones I have. And one of those two, container gets populated after it loops the info, but it should be, since I have it logged and it shows before the error on line 83.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error happens because the arrays. The code works fine with the test arrays. Could you show, how EXACTLY look the arrays `container` and `data`?

Comment: I can! 
https://pastebin.com/s0JABm2k

That's partial since it's 30k+ the output would be to large, those two snippets are the logs. of both data and container

Comment: Thank you for clarification. It's obvious now. The array `container` shorter than the array `data`. So there is two possible solution: iterate though the shorter array `container` like this: `for (let sku in arrayTwo_obj) {` or use `try {} catch() {}`. The problem was that the bigger object `arrayOne_obj` (data) has some `sku` sub objects that the smaller object `arrayTwo_obj` (container) hasn't. This why the error appears.

Comment: Just in case the code that loops through a smaller array is here: https://pastebin.com/ra5GSznr And here is the same code with `try {} catch(e) {}`: https://pastebin.com/UV5VsRjZ They both get the same correct result. But the first solution is more efficient if you sure that the 'container' array is always shorter than 'data'

Comment: Wow, the for worked perfectly, didn't try the try - catch because I know the data is always shorter.

Thank you a lot Yuri!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this in two steps:

1. Find greatest ones of each in `arrOne`
2. Compare with corresponding one in `arrTwo`

You can use this nice function for that:

```js
const arrOne = [
  {
    sku: "PD-1000-B",
    price: 9678.16
  },
  {
    sku: "PD-1000-B",
    price: 9800.00
  },
  {
    sku: "PD-1007-C",
    price: 9714.16
  },
  {
    sku: "PD-1007-C",
    price: 9270.00
  }
]

const arrTwo = [
 {sku: "PD-1000-B", id:1622.0, price:8145.9},
 {sku: "PD-1007-A", id:1624.0, price:9678.16},
 {sku: "PD-1007-C", id:1627.0, price:9478.16},
]

const findAllHighest = (arr) => {
  // 1) get highest one of each in arrOne
  const arrOneGreatest = arr.reduce((prev, cur) => {
    if(!prev[cur.sku]){
      prev[cur.sku] = cur
      return prev
    }

    if(cur.price > prev[cur.sku].price){
      prev[cur.sku] = cur
    }
    return prev
  }, {})
  
  // match to arrayTwo
  const result = arrTwo.map(el => {
    const arrOneObj = Object.values(arrOneGreatest).find(n => n.sku === el.sku)

    if(!arrOneObj)
      return el

    if(arrOneObj.price > el.price)
      el.price = arrOneObj.price
    return el
  }, [])
  
  return result
}

console.log(findAllHighest(arrOne))
```

```css
 .as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I'm still pretty much a noob in JS.
This works partially, even though it compares it and updates only the biggest price it still returns all items in the array I think, asuming I'm using your code correctly since I don't entirely understand it.
`[{sku=PD-1000-B, id=1622.0, price=8145.9}, {id=1624.0, price=60000.0, sku=PD-1007-A}, {price=8023.12, id=1625.0, sku=PD-1014}, {sku=PD-1026, price=7139.21, id=1627.0}, {id=1629.0, price=650000.0, sku=PD-1028}, {id=1630.0, sku=PD-1028-B, price=13000.0}, {price=9491.81, id=1631.0, sku=PD-1029A}]`

Comment: I know I'm not telling you much now that I read my reply.

basically, the first one didn't have a price change, the second one yes and so fort. In your example it only shows the ones that had a price change.

Comment: Total items? About 30k per array. I'm gonna batch update by 100 per update.

Comment: I spotted a mistake in the code. It was returning less items than arrTwo. Fixed now. 'I'm gonna batch update by 100 per update'. It is ok, Try and see

Comment: 30k per array but I'm testing it with very few products, only 10.
from your code I switched

`console.log(findAllHighest(arrOne))`
with
`console.log(findAllHighest(data))`
and
`const result = arrTwo.map(el =>`
with
`const result = container.map(el =>`

I feel that is all I should've modified right?

Comment: It works perfectly fine but It's not quite what I was looking for.
What I was looking for exactly is to have a new array with id, sku and updated price only when a price was actually updated. so if I had 
`id: 1, sku: 1, price: 5,`
`id: 2, sku: 2, price: 10`

and 
`sku: 2, price 15,`
`sku: 1, price 1`

I want a new array that only contains

`sku: 2, price 15` and nothing else.

It's still a great answer.

Comment: So you want the ids out? You can modify the code to disclude it in the .map function

Comment: Actually no, I set a very bad example I guess.
What I want is to add to a new array only the id, sku and price when the price changes, if the price doesn't change (isn't >) then I don't want it in the new array.