# save JSON value in provided folder in Javascript / node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, nodes

```js
let obj={
 print:{
   "2343192u4":{
     id:"01",
     name:"linux file",
     location:"System config"
    },
   "23438ufsdjh8":{
     id:"02",
     name:"windows file",
     location:"System config"
   }
 },
 hardware:{
   "9058t05":{
     no:"ct-01",
     refrence:"down-tPO-01"
    }
 },
 stack:{
   "345t5fdfve":{
     option1:"prefer first lost",
     failure:"run backup"
    }
 },
 backupdir:{
   "cjksder8982w":{
   files:"config file.json",
   execute:"run after failure"
   }
 }
};


let Array=[{
  filepath:"print"
 },
 {
  filepath:"hardware"
 },
 {
  filepath:"stack"
 },
 {
  filepath:"backupdir"
 },
];

Array.map((file)=>{
//console.log(file.filepath)
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key)=>{
 
 if(key===file.filepath){
// fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname,file.filepath,"system.json"), JSON.stringify(Object.values(obj)[0], null, 4))

console.log("yes");
 }
})
});
```

I am trying to fetch key from the `obj` JSON object and compare it with the Array filepath so I can push the value in created json file

here by using fs I am trying to create folder which I got from the array

```
fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname,file.filepath,"system.json"));
```

by which I created folder and file system.json in it and I am trying to compare the key from the obj json and filepath from the array
and trying to put like this

### print/system.json

```
{
   "2343192u4":{
     id:"01",
     name:"linux file",
     location:"System config"
    },
   "23438ufsdjh8":{
     id:"02",
     name:"windows file",
     location:"System config"
   }
 }
```

### hardware/system.json

```
{
   "9058t05":{
     no:"ct-01",
     refrence:"down-tPO-01"
   }
}
```

### and so on ...

but the problem is when I do this

```
JSON.stringify(Object.values(obj)[0], null, 4)
```

I am getting same output in every file

### print/system.json

```
{
   "2343192u4":{
     id:"01",
     name:"linux file",
     location:"System config"
    },
   "23438ufsdjh8":{
     id:"02",
     name:"windows file",
     location:"System config"
   }
 }
```

### hardware/system.json

```
{
   "2343192u4":{
     id:"01",
     name:"linux file",
     location:"System config"
    },
   "23438ufsdjh8":{
     id:"02",
     name:"windows file",
     location:"System config"
   }
 }
```

### and so on ...

here `print hardware stack backupdir` always get changed and there are multiple more files as this is system random generated name thats why I have to compare and the key from object and make a directory of this name

how can I push them in different different folder with there respective value

Comment: Loop over the values instead of always referencing the first (`[0]`). In fact you can loop over the key-value pairs using `Object.entries` so you can use the directory based on the key and save the file inside based on the value.

Comment: How @CherryDT ? I didn't get it

Comment: `for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) await fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, key, 'system.json', JSON.stringify(value, null, 4)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname,file.filepath,"system.json"),
   JSON.stringify(Object.values(obj)[0], null, 4))
```

(which only looks at the first property value in `obj`) to

```
fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname,file.filepath,"system.json"),
 JSON.stringify(obj[key], null, 4))
```

which look up the property object in `obj` using the `key` value obtained from the `Array` entry being processed.

The use of `forEach` in `Object.keys(obj).forEach((key)=>{` prevents stopping the search if a matching filepath is found. Another option would be to use a `for of` loop that breaks out if a file name has been found:

```
Array.forEach((file)=>{
  for( let key of Object.keys(obj)) { 
    if(key===file.filepath) {
      fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname,file.filepath,"system.json"),
        JSON.stringify(obj[key], null, 4)); 
      break;      
    }
  }
});
```

---

Also: avoid using the names of global constructors such as  `Array` as variable names - it's a bug waiting to happen :-)

Comment: actually here I have provided name `array` in my code its having different name 

Comment: and in place of `forEach` I should use `for..in` ?

Comment: A `for of` loop is usually recommended for Array entries because it [returns the values of numerically indexed items in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29285897/5217142)

Comment: Careful, right now you create a _global variable_ `key` here because you are missing a declaration keyword! Also, suggestion: Use `Object.entries` instead of `Object.keys` so that you don't have `obj[key]` further down - you'd just do `for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj))` and then you'd have `JSON.stringify(value, null, 4)` below. Also, the `.map` doesn't seem to be very useful, you aren't mapping to anything...

Comment: @CherryDT thanks for the additional suggestions - I've edited to declare `key` before use and replaced `map` with `forEach` in the outer loop. I recommend always running JavaScript in strict node if for no other reason than the compiler generates an error if you fail to declare variables when executing the code. I agree the code could benefit from further improvements but personally would probably have iterated over entries of `obj` in the outer loop if rewriting the code entirely.