# How can I list all the records to see if they are duplicated?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, discord.js

I have a problem that I cannot resolve. I have a table in MongoDB, and this is structure:

```
const shopEconomy = new mongoose.Schema({
    guildID: { type: String },
    name: { type: String },
    value: { type: Number },
    description: { type: String },
    rolereq: { type: String },
    roleadd: { type: String },
    roleremove: { type: String },
    buyinfo: { type: String }
});
```

I need to list all names from the table (shopData.name) and then check if the typed name exists in the database. I tried to do something like the one below, but it doesn't work.

```
const shopData = await shopEconomy.find({ guildID: message.guild.id });

        let categories = [];
        let data = new Object();
        for(const i in shopData){
            data += `${shopData[i].name}\n`

            categories.push(data)
        }
```

Could someone take a look at this and help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title of the question does not quite match the description of the question.  Given the description, let's assume the typed name is assigned to var `typedName`.
Let's also assume that you have bound your `shopEconomy` schema to a model that will actually interact with a mongodb collection called `shopData`.  Then this will iterate all the docs in the `shopData`:

```js
var found = false;
cursor = db.shopData.find();  // get EVERYTHING
cursor.forEach(function(doc) {
  print(doc['name']);
  if(doc['name'] == typedName) {
    found = true;
  }
});
if(found) {
  print(typedName,"was found");
}
```

It is likely that the OP wants to find duplicate name in the collection, for which this pipeline will work:

```js
db.shopData.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: '$name', N:{$sum:1}} },
    {$match: {'N':{$gt:1}}}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the issue here comes from the use of a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop which treats `shopData` as an object and loops over all properties of it. Instead try using a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop which treats `shopData` as an array and loops over all objects in it.

```
...

for(const i of shopData) {
    data += `${i.name}\n`

    ...
}
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285897/what-is-the-difference-between-for-in-and-for-of-statements) on `for...in` vs `for...of` and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript) on JavaScript loops.