# Looping on a Record in Vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js

How do we loop over a variable of type `Record<string, string[]>` in Vue? My variable contains a key-value dictionary that looks like this:

```
errors = {
  'username': ['Must contain at least 1 special character', 'Min length is 6'],
  'password': ['Required']
}
```

I tried this but Vue (or TS or ESLint, not sure) is not happy:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="e in errors" :key="e">
    {{ e }}
    <ul>
      <li v-for="e2 in e" :key="e2">
        {{ e2 }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It shows this error for the first `:key` above:

> `Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol | undefined'

BTW, I'm using Vue 3 with TS. `errors` is part of an interface and is defined as `Record<string, string[]>`.

Comment: In the second loop, it's an array, so it should be `e2 of e`.

Comment: @caTS: Is there a difference between the usage of `of` and `in` in Vue?

Comment: Vue uses JS' loops, so you can find the difference between them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285897/what-is-the-difference-between-for-in-and-for-of-statements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. The outer loop needs to declare its variable as array like this:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="[cat, errs] in msg.errors" :key="cat">
    {{ cat }}
    <ul>
      <li v-for="e2 of errs" :key="e2">
        {{ e2 }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```