# How to disable a button with a certain value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How are the buttons disabled from a specific list of values, in my situation?

I tried to do it like this:

```js
    var pls = [[45], [1]];
    for(var el in pls){
        $.each($('.seat'), function(){
            var attr_el = $(this).attr("value");
            if(attr_el == el){
                $(this).prop("disabled",true);
            };
        });
    };
```

```css
.seat{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="seat" value="1">&nbsp;</button>
<button class="seat" value="45">&nbsp;</button>
<button class="seat" value="100">&nbsp;</button>
```

But only the `1` button is disabled, not the `45` button.

Comment: Typo?  `$each.(` looks like it should be `$.each(` instead.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but it didn't help :)

Comment: Can you provide more information about the error?  Which specific line of code does it reference?  Can you replicate the error with a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193)?

Comment: It looks like each element of `pls` is itself an array.  Does `if($(this).attr("value") == el[0]){` help?

Comment: @Егор: Regarding the update... (1) Please clean up the post, the runnable snippet is malformed.  (2) The updated code still has the same typo.  (3) When I correct that typo, I no longer get that error.  Please take some time to debug and confirm, and to specify exactly what you're asking about.

Comment: @David: yes, but disablid is only 1 item, but not all of the list

Comment: @Егор: *"yes, but"* - Then [your previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77841230/how-to-disable-a-button-with-a-certain-value-using-jquery-in-django?noredirect=1#comment137229147_77841230) was a lie?  Please be clear about the specific problem you are observing and the specific question you are asking.  Your code had a typo.  That typo produced a syntax error.  After several tries, you have corrected that typo. Now the code no longer produces that syntax error. The question above is asking about that syntax error.  Which has already been answered. Please clarify in the question.

Comment: Thank you, David, and I'm sorry. I'm a new user and I'm just learning. I've read the guidelines for writing questions, but it's hard to ask a good question the first time.

Comment: The question already has close-votes from the original typo, but now is also a duplicate of: [Difference between ( for... in ) and ( for... of ) statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285897/difference-between-for-in-and-for-of-statements)  You're just using the wrong loop iteration, referencing array indexes instead of array values.

Comment: `el` is an array, `attr_el` is a string. They can never be equal. Why is `pls` a 2-dimension array?

Comment: @Barmar: `pls` is two-dimensional, because this is the only way I was able to transfer the data I needed using json. This was described in the question earlier, but the editor changed my question to make it more readable.

Comment: I can't imagine any reason why you couldn't transfer `[45, 1]` using JSON.

Comment: @Barmar: I could explain, but this is a separate topic for discussion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to loop over the elements, you can use an attribute selector.

```js
var pls = [
  [45],
  [1]
];
$.each(pls, (i, [el]) => 
  $(`.seat[value=${el}]`).prop('disabled', true)
);
```

```css
.seat {
  background-color: green;
}

.seat:disabled {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="seat" value="1">&nbsp;</button>
<button class="seat" value="45">&nbsp;</button>
<button class="seat" value="100">&nbsp;</button>
```

I used destructuring in the callback argument list to extract the first element of each nested array in `pls`.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, I changed `for...in` on `for...of`, to take not indexes, but array values. Since we are working with **an array inside an array**, `el` is also an array with one element. So, we change `el` to `el[0]` to take the first (and only) argument.

```js
    var pls = [[45], [1]];
    for(var el of pls){
        $.each($('.seat'), function(){
            var attr_el = $(this).attr("value");
            if(attr_el == el[0]){
                $(this).prop("disabled",true);
            };
        });
    };
```

```css
.seat{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="seat" value="1">&nbsp;</button>
<button class="seat" value="45">&nbsp;</button>
<button class="seat" value="100">&nbsp;</button>
```

Comment: Is this the answer? If so, please add a comment explaining how you fixed the issue.  If not, please remove it and add the correct code snippet to the question instead (using the edit functionality)