# Iterating through an array of objects using for each or for in

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Please how do one iterate over a array of object like
using "for each" or "for in or is there another way

```
{
    "cards": [
        {
            "des": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ut diam ac felis placerat consequat in vitae justo. Curabitur porta et dolor ac. Morbi quis elementum ipsum",
            "cardName": "Aenean nec sem vestibulum",
            "imgSrc": "Layer1.png",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "des": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ut diam ac felis placerat consequat in vitae justo. Curabitur porta et dolor ac. Morbi quis elementum ipsum",
            "cardName": "Aenean nec sem vestibulum",
            "imgSrc": "tom-jagger.jpg",
            "id": 2
        },
        {
            "des": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ut diam ac felis placerat consequat in vitae justo. Curabitur porta et dolor ac. Morbi quis elementum ipsum",
            "cardName": "Aenean nec sem vestibulum",
            "imgSrc": "Layer3.png",
            "id": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

i need the output to be each object in the array
Also lets say i want to do the iteration using the "id" parameter. how do i do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: you can find your answer here :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634654/what-is-the-difference-between-for-in-and-for-each-in-in-javascript

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626735/how-to-loop-through-an-array-containing-objects-and-access-their-properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of options availbe to you for iterating (looping) through data like this. The more common methods would be:

Iteration via `Array#forEach()`:

```
data.cards.forEach(function(card) {
  console.log(card);
});
```

Iteration via an iterator using the `for-of` construct:

```
for(const card of data.cards) {
  console.log(card);
};
```

Iteration via an iterator using the `for-in` construct:

```
for(const key in data.cards) {
  const value = data.cards[key];
  console.log(value);
};
```

Here is a working snippet showing these in action:

```js
var data = {
    "cards": [
        {
            "des": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ut diam ac felis placerat consequat in vitae justo. Curabitur porta et dolor ac. Morbi quis elementum ipsum",
            "cardName": "Aenean nec sem vestibulum",
            "imgSrc": "Layer1.png",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "des": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ut diam ac felis placerat consequat in vitae justo. Curabitur porta et dolor ac. Morbi quis elementum ipsum",
            "cardName": "Aenean nec sem vestibulum",
            "imgSrc": "tom-jagger.jpg",
            "id": 2
        },
        {
            "des": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ut diam ac felis placerat consequat in vitae justo. Curabitur porta et dolor ac. Morbi quis elementum ipsum",
            "cardName": "Aenean nec sem vestibulum",
            "imgSrc": "Layer3.png",
            "id": 3
        }
    ]
};

// Array.forEach method
data.cards.forEach(function(card) {
  console.log(card);
});

// for-of loop
for(const card of data.cards) {
  console.log(card);
};

// for-in loop
for(const key in data.cards) {
  const value = data.cards[key];
  console.log(value);
};
```

Comment: thanks , but lets say i want to do the iteration using the "id" parameter. how do i do this

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to iterate via a `key`, using the `for - in` loop construct - is that correct? Just updated the answer to demonstrate that - hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try forEach

```js
let k={
    "cards": [
        {
            "des": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ut diam ac felis placerat consequat in vitae justo. Curabitur porta et dolor ac. Morbi quis elementum ipsum",
            "cardName": "Aenean nec sem vestibulum",
            "imgSrc": "Layer1.png",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "des": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ut diam ac felis placerat consequat in vitae justo. Curabitur porta et dolor ac. Morbi quis elementum ipsum",
            "cardName": "Aenean nec sem vestibulum",
            "imgSrc": "tom-jagger.jpg",
            "id": 2
        },
        {
            "des": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ut diam ac felis placerat consequat in vitae justo. Curabitur porta et dolor ac. Morbi quis elementum ipsum",
            "cardName": "Aenean nec sem vestibulum",
            "imgSrc": "Layer3.png",
            "id": 3
        }
    ]
}

k.cards.forEach(a=>{
console.log(a.imgSrc)
console.log(a.des)
console.log(a.cardName)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure - simplest way is [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
 

const cards = [
    {
        "des": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ut diam ac felis placerat consequat in vitae justo. Curabitur porta et dolor ac. Morbi quis elementum ipsum",
        "cardName": "Aenean nec sem vestibulum",
        "imgSrc": "Layer1.png",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "des": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ut diam ac felis placerat consequat in vitae justo. Curabitur porta et dolor ac. Morbi quis elementum ipsum",
        "cardName": "Aenean nec sem vestibulum",
        "imgSrc": "tom-jagger.jpg",
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "des": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ut diam ac felis placerat consequat in vitae justo. Curabitur porta et dolor ac. Morbi quis elementum ipsum",
        "cardName": "Aenean nec sem vestibulum",
        "imgSrc": "Layer3.png",
        "id": 3
    }
];

cards.forEach(card => console.log(card));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

```
let cards =[
    {
        "des": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ut diam ac felis placerat consequat in vitae justo. Curabitur porta et dolor ac. Morbi quis elementum ipsum",
        "cardName": "Aenean nec sem vestibulum",
        "imgSrc": "Layer1.png",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "des": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ut diam ac felis placerat consequat in vitae justo. Curabitur porta et dolor ac. Morbi quis elementum ipsum",
        "cardName": "Aenean nec sem vestibulum",
        "imgSrc": "tom-jagger.jpg",
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "des": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ut diam ac felis placerat consequat in vitae justo. Curabitur porta et dolor ac. Morbi quis elementum ipsum",
        "cardName": "Aenean nec sem vestibulum",
        "imgSrc": "Layer3.png",
        "id": 3
    }
];
```

...
...

```
for(var i in cards){
    console.log(cards[i]);
}
```

or

```
cards.map(function(each_item, index_key){
    console.log(each_item);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want to iterate over it and return or not.

You can do the following to modify the response over the iteration or just return every single object in a loop:

> Map: array.map will return https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
array.map(item => console.log(item));
```

> Foreach: method executes a provided function once for each array element.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

```
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

array1.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data={
    "cards": [
        {
            "des": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ut diam ac felis placerat consequat in vitae justo. Curabitur porta et dolor ac. Morbi quis elementum ipsum",
            "cardName": "Aenean nec sem vestibulum",
            "imgSrc": "Layer1.png",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "des": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ut diam ac felis placerat consequat in vitae justo. Curabitur porta et dolor ac. Morbi quis elementum ipsum",
            "cardName": "Aenean nec sem vestibulum",
            "imgSrc": "tom-jagger.jpg",
            "id": 2
        },
        {
            "des": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ut diam ac felis placerat consequat in vitae justo. Curabitur porta et dolor ac. Morbi quis elementum ipsum",
            "cardName": "Aenean nec sem vestibulum",
            "imgSrc": "Layer3.png",
            "id": 3
        }
    ]
}
function match(data,id){
return data.cards.filter(a=>id==a.id)
}
console.log(match(data,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using forEach and forIn.You can use javascript map function.You can also use third party modules such as Lodash which provides lots of useful helper functions. Here is the link [Lodash Documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11)

```
var _= require('lodash');
const cards = [
  {
    "des": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ut diam ac felis placerat consequat in vitae justo. Curabitur porta et dolor ac. Morbi quis elementum ipsum",
    "cardName": "Aenean nec sem vestibulum",
    "imgSrc": "Layer1.png",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "des": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ut diam ac felis placerat consequat in vitae justo. Curabitur porta et dolor ac. Morbi quis elementum ipsum",
    "cardName": "Aenean nec sem vestibulum",
    "imgSrc": "tom-jagger.jpg",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "des": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ut diam ac felis placerat consequat in vitae justo. Curabitur porta et dolor ac. Morbi quis elementum ipsum",
    "cardName": "Aenean nec sem vestibulum",
    "imgSrc": "Layer3.png",
    "id": 3
  }
]

_.forEach(cards,item => {

  console.log("cards has:",item)
})
```